# Send NFC records from Activity to Fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, nfc

I am working on a project that has a tabbed activity, there one tab write to NFC tag while the second tab read from NFC tag. My writing tab works perfectly but my reading tab is not. What I want to do is to send NFC records (data) from my tabbed activity (containing the logic of reading NFC tag) to text fields found in the fragment. This is my code for Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient, container, false);

    txtName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pName);
    txtCountry = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pCountry);
    txtID = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pID);
    readbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.nfcReadBtn);

    readbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            MainActivity homeActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

            MyNfcRecords readMessage= homeActivity.readFromNFC();
            txtName.setText(readMessage.key1);
            txtCountry.setText(readMessage.key2);
            txtID.setText(readMessage.key3);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

To make my life easier, I have created a class called MyNfcRecods that have multiple strings:

```
public class MyNfcRecords {
String key1;
String key2;
String key3;
MyNfcRecords(String k1, String k2, String k3){
    key1 =k1;
    key2=k2;
    key3=k3;
   }
}
```

Finally, these are the methods I am using for reading NFC tag (in tabbed Activity):

```
public MyNfcRecords readFromNFC() {
    Log.d("my tag", "readFromNFC: ");
    Parcelable[] parcelables = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    Log.d("here",getIntent().toString());
    if(parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0) {

        return readTextFromMessage((NdefMessage) parcelables[0]);
    }
    return null;
}

private MyNfcRecords readTextFromMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    Log.d("my tag", "readTextFromMessage: ");
    NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();
    if(ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length>0){

        NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
        NdefRecord ndefRecord2 = ndefRecords[1];
        NdefRecord ndefRecord3 = ndefRecords[2];

        String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);
        String tagContent2 = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord2);
        String tagContent3 = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord3);
        return  new MyNfcRecords(tagContent, tagContent2, tagContent3);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF records found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   return null;

}

public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord)
{
    String tagContent = null;
    try {
        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1,
                payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return tagContent;
}
```

When I run the code I am getting (ava.lang.String .....MyNfcRecords.key1' on a null object reference). Am I doing something wrong with how I am retrieving data from NFC tag?

Comment: You are doing it in a very messy manner , no doubt its crashing, I would suggest that your read in main activity and then pass that data to `Fragment` using bundles

Comment: try using EventBus to pass the data

Comment: I actually solved the problem by moving the code from readFromNFC method to onNewIntent method